# Assets Error: Unknown or bad format (years) at position 0 (y)

Tags: assets, database, timezone

I am getting a new error, after no apparent updates from me or the client.
The error only appears on pages with this one particular field.

> "DateInterval::createFromDateString(): Unknown or bad format ( years) at position 0 (y): The timezone could not be found in the database"

(then a whole description of errors after it - the first from `/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/DateTimeHelper.php`)

The field in question is an asset field (within a Matrix field).
The files are uploaded / stored in an S3 bucket.

Everything was working fine for a few months, now any site or admin page with content from this particular field throws that error.

I have looked at the database and could not spot any obvious errors (to my eyes anyway).

I've also cleared caches and updated asset indexes

Any ideas as to what I am looking for / do next?

Comment: seems like its DateInterval::createFromDateString.

Comment: Thanks Priti - Not sure what you mean - have you seen this error before? any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Well I haven't seen this error before but as going through your error message it seems like it's PHP error.

Answer (score 1):

In case this effects anyone else, here's what I did to get working:

- update craft to latest version (in this case 3.1.24)
- *flush* cache using Blitz cache plugin (clear is not enough)
- use Cloudfront and not just S3
- update all asset indexes in cms

That seemed to have done the trick.